# Add and Remove values in a hidden field array, without submitting form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to manipulate the values of a hidden field, without submitting the form.
The closest I found is [Add and Remove values in a hidden field array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23832502/add-and-remove-values-in-a-hidden-field-array)

Problem I have with this is that it submits the form. In my project I'm not ready to submit the form yet. There are more questions to be asked.
[Here's a JSFiddle of my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/FlyingDog/mQ6dU/177/).

I feel like I'm missing something like a 'return false'.

Thanks for the help.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
addToArray: function(value) {
    return this.filter(":input").val(function(i, v) {
       var arr = v.split(',');
       arr.push(value);
       return arr.join(',');
    }).end();
},
removeFromArray: function(value) {
    return this.filter(":input").val(function(i, v) {
       return $.grep(v.split(','), function(val) {  
                return val != value;
              }).join(',');
    }).end();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `return false;` in the onClick code:

```
<button onclick='$("#myField").addToArray("21"); return false;'>
```

To prevent submission.

I think you should ask a separate question, but I'm diving into this anyway.  I modified the HTML [in the jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prohner/41h555kf/2/).  Since you're using jQuery I took advantage of the click event handler.  Initially I created a single handler to see what code was required.  It looked like this initially:

```
$( "#strength" ).click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  if ($( '#goals' ).val().indexOf(',strength') >= 0) {
    $( '#goals' ).val($( '#goals' ).val().replace(',strength', ''));
    $( this ).removeClass('button');
    $( this ).addClass('buttonSelected');
  } else {
    $( '#goals' ).val($( '#goals' ).val() + ',strength');
    $( this ).removeClass('buttonSelected');
    $( this ).addClass('button');
  }
});
```

That was an okay starting point to figure out the required code.  However I didn't want to repeat that code for each of the buttons.  So I factored out the code that I knew could be reused for the other buttons.  So it looked like this:

```
$( "#strength" ).click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  toggle(',strength', this);
});

function toggle(str, thisObj) {
  if ($( '#goals' ).val().indexOf(str) >= 0) {
    console.log(str + ' is already selected');
    $( '#goals' ).val($( '#goals' ).val().replace(str, ''));
    $( thisObj ).removeClass('buttonSelected');
    $( thisObj ).addClass('button');
  } else {
    console.log(str + ' is about to be selected');
    $( '#goals' ).val($( '#goals' ).val() + str);
    $( thisObj ).removeClass('button');
    $( thisObj ).addClass('buttonSelected');
  }
}
```

Then it is pretty straightforward to handle the additional buttons with some repetitive code:

```
$( "#weight" ).click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
  toggle(',weight', this);
});

$( "#tone" ).click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
  toggle(',tone', this);
});
```

You may be able to decrease the repetition, but I'm tired and hungry.  Hope this helps you out!

Comment: I am trying to also change the applied CSS class to the buttons. [New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FlyingDog/yo49c9ko/)
The CSS switch was working previously, but is no longer.  Suggestions?
I need to get only the selected values in the array, and reflect if they get unslected, then removed from the array. I tried adding the trogger for the addToArray to my existing toggleClass, but it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to preventdefault event.

Here's the solution:

```
            event.preventDefault();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4kbq0veq/

Comment: I am trying to also change the applied CSS class to the buttons. [New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FlyingDog/yo49c9ko/)
The CSS switch was working previously, but is no longer.  Suggestions?
I need to get only the selected values in the array, and reflect if they get unslected, then removed from the array. I tried adding the trogger for the addToArray to my existing toggleClass, but it fails.

Comment: You may want to just attach separate listener for Button like this:`jQuery("button").click(function() { $( this ).toggleClass( "buttonSelected" ); });`